# CSS Display: none a better solution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, dom

I am using DIVI, Wordpress and I have this video I set as a background for Desktop but I disable it for Mobile and Tablets but here's the thing, what the Disable option does is just a display:none so the video is still being loaded DOM.

Is there a way to totally block an object from loading? so it does affect the loading time on mobile devices?

Share your thoughts, Please

Comment: Any specific probelm with code ?

Comment: From your experience, how can you block an object from loading in DOM?

Comment: by deleting that element from html @DaveBud

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt: It will still start the download. Even more of a waste now, because you triggered the download, downloaded it and the element is gone now :)

Comment: To counter the downvoter: IMO this is a legit question if you're a beginner. Magaging resourceflow is something you have to be told before it's obvious in most cases.

Comment: Deleting it from the HMTL? Sorry, I am new at this. Can I also create some sort of Javascript conditional so it does load in mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, flip your logic:

**Never load the clip, *unless* it's a capable device.**

You can use javascript to check if the screen width is broad enough (or even better: Check if the device is capable of your clip, some tablets in a wifi can often display it as well).
If you decide it can be played, add a video element to the page (or add the `src` to your element) and trigger a play event.

*BTW: This trick can be applied to many resources, eg images as well.*

Comment: But is this done with Javascript? lol Sorry bro I am new at this

Comment: Yes, just as the first sentence of the paragraph says ;)

Comment: lol Sorry this is too much to ask but do you have some example where you implemented something like this? some piece of code. I understand if you decline my request :P

Comment: This site is not the kind of site to hand you working code, sorry. Just google 'javascript detect screenwidth', 'javascript add video element'

Comment: Sweet! that'll do the trick, Thanks for showing me the way Kind Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions Ian kindly made, here is my working solution.

Firstly, I changed each video's child source elements to have an attribute data-src like so:

```
<video id="my-id">    
   <source data-src="somevideo.mp4">
</video>
```

Then, after performing a mobile check using the script available at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ which I modified to include iPads etc (related SO answer here) I simply used the following script to automatically update the src attribute of each video (if we're on desktop in my case):

```
var sources = document.querySelectorAll('video#my-id source');
// Define the video object this source is contained inside
var video = document.querySelector('video#my-id');
for(var i = 0; i<sources.length;i++) {
  sources[i].setAttribute('src', sources[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
}
// If for some reason we do want to load the video after, for desktop as opposed to mobile (I'd imagine), use videojs API to load
video.load();
```

And that's it! Nothing loads on mobile devices anymore and I can have fairly granular control over the devices it will or won't load on.

Hope this helps somebody.